# R: what does the color gradient in fancyRpartPlot() mean?

Tags: r, tree

http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2013/06/plotting-classification-and-regression-trees-with-plotrpart.html

I was looking at ways to plot regression trees in R, and I came across the fancyRpartPlot() function in the `rattle` package. I looked at the example tree on the page I linked to above, and I noticed that there is a gradient to the colors in the boxes. Nodes 1 and 2 have a darker hue of green than the other PS boxes. And node 27 has the darkest hue of blue compared to the other WS boxes. What do the differences in color mean?

Comment: I can't seem to find `fancyRpartTree` in `rattle` package. Did you mean `fancyRpartPlot`?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Yes, I meant fancyRpartPlot. Sorry about that. I will change it in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm far from a pro in this area (so please excuse imperfect terminology), but a more obvious example of my own helped me to figure this out recently. The gradient represents the accuracy of that node. I've included my example here as I find it far clearer:

http://s3.postimg.org/6lx10824z/Screen_Shot_2015_03_09_at_20_18_44.png

Green nodes represent individuals classified by the tree as A, blue nodes are those classified as B and orange nodes are classified as C. The gradient is a visual representation of the three numbers in the middle of the nodes: bearing in mind that levels of a factor are by default in alphabetical order, the first of these three numbers is the proportion of individuals in that node that were actually classified as the first level, (A), in my data; the second number is the proportion that were actually classified as B, and the third the proportion that were C.

If you check out the extremely bright orange node in the bottom right, classified by the model as C, the third number indicates that 89% of these individuals really were Cs, while 2% were As and 9% Bs. The brightest green (A) node (second from left at the bottom) consisted of 90% actual As, with a 10% error rate. Conversely, the really pale green node (middle left-ish) had a 61% error rate.

As I say, this was only my interpretation, but it does also apply to your example: the darkest green node in the bottom left had an error rate of only 9%, and the darkest blue node third from the right only 16%.

Hope this helps!